# Graphic Card wont let me install Ubuntu

Tags: ati, radeon, 13.10, gpu

I am new to Ubuntu, never used it and wanted to try the new 13.10, I downloaded the 13.10 x64 version and made and bootable usb drive, after I boot the pc with the drive in and select try Ubuntu without installing the thing just freezes and after a while random numbers appear on the screen and after a while it freezes again, this also happened when a while back I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10

AMD athlon 64 X2 Dual core 4400+ 230GHz
4gb RAM
and ATI HD 5450 1gb DDR3

The reason I think its the graphic card is that the words and numbers that pop up while I try to install it say something about GPU and Radeon.

I tried to remove the card and it works fine but as soon as I plug it in I cant boot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

To determine your video card make and model, run this command from a terminal window after booting from a LiveCD:

*lspci | grep VGA*

More detailed information can be found by running

*sudo lshw -C video*

and posting the results here would help.

To make a postable log file do

*lspci | grep VGA > logfile.txt

sudo lshw -C video >> logfile.txt*

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCards shows the ATI Radeon HD 5450 Cedar PRO/radeon supports compiz and Unity with the default open source driver as of Natty (11.04) so the open source driver should be OK.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI has specific instructions to help.

Comment: If the graphic card is not removed i cant even boot from a live CD

Comment: can i just plug the Video card in while the pc is running and install the drivers without rebooting the pc?

Comment: No, please do not plug in the graphics card while the PC is running. Sounds like a different video card is needed. You can validate that by installing a different version of Linux other than Ubuntu 13.10. When you try to install, say, Xubuntu 12.04 from http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/ or a local mirror (from http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/ page down to 12.04LTS and choose the country closest to you), are you able to complete the install successfully?